# What should I do after finishing a git repo?

Tags: git, github

Like after I'm all done with it never gonna touch it again.
Do I just delete the folder from my system and its good and over?

Comment: What is your objective?

Comment: Yes, and you'll also need to delete it from GitHub

Comment: My objective would be to leave the project sitting somewhere for some reason? I don't want to always have a git connection on my laptop for projects that I'll be done with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete it locally and delete it from GitHub. Anyone who has the source code can repush it to GitHub though through their account and all commits would be retained though.

Comment: Do I need to do anything about the remotes or no?

Comment: No, remotes are stored in your `.git` folder. If you delete the `.git` folder, you'll see that you can no longer access git and no more remotes as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting your local copy should do the job.

About removing it from Github: do you really need to do it? Maybe other people is using it, or will use it in the future. If not, and you have contributors, you can probably just leave the project in hands of them.

I don't think the concept of "finishing" is the most accurate one here in terms of an Open Source project lifecycle.

Comment: I don't think the concept of "finishing" is ever really a concept in software development, open source or not.  (personally, I'd never ditch the repo... back it up to deep storage if you want, but that's your bible - don't get rid of it!)

Comment: I'm too young to do anything rn and basically doing random stuff and practicing got rn